# Profile Field Search module not importing bundle

Tags: 7, users

We are attempting to use the module **[Profile field search](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_field_search)** to search profiles for terms defined using **[profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2)**, however, this is not working. I have set the **profile entity** field to **Profile2** and the **profile bundle** to our custom profile type, but the terms won't appear in the search fields and won't return profiles when those terms are entered in the text box.

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated. If you require further information, please ask.

New to this process and not very familiar with it yet.